# Three quick beginner questions about Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability

Newbie learning about conditional expectation in Sheldon Ross's book and I had some basic questions to help my understanding.

**Question 1**

For a discrete or continuous RV $X$, is it always true that $E[X|X] = X$?

My attempt: $E[X|X] = \sum_{x} x P(X=x | X=x_0)= x_0 $ and as a result, the value that $E[X|X]$ takes will be one of the possible values of $X$ with probability based on the pmf of $X$, therefore $E[X|X] = X$

**Question 2**

Let's say $X$ represents a dice roll. Then how would you describe in your own words what the $E[X|X]$ is saying? Besides saying that it is $X$.

**Question 3**

What is the diference between $E[X|Y]$ and $E[X|Y=y]$ ? Is it just a notation or convention thing or is there a fundamental difference? I want to say the former always represents a RV and the latter could be either constant or a RV (which is confusing).

Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: I think you can refer to the formal definition of conditional expectation. You can find it on Wikipedia

Comment: I think $E[X|X] = X$ is maybe too trivial for the wiki... I admit these are very beginner questions. Sometimes it just helps me to write things in my own words and get confirmation from experts on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try Question 3 first:

- $E[X\mid Y=y]$ is just a value, which may change with $y$ if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, and it may only make sense if $y$ is in the support of $Y$.  So you might say $E[X\mid Y=y]$ is a function of $y$, say $h(y)$
- If we apply this function to $Y$, in the same way we would might with any other function of a random variable, we get another random variable $h(Y)$ which in a sense is $E[X\mid Y]$
- In summary, $E[X\mid Y=y]$ is a value which may depend on $y$, while $E[X\mid Y]$ is a random variable.  They are not the same

This makes Question 1 easier:

- Clearly $E[X \mid X=x]=x$, providing that $x$ is in the support of $X$.
- So the function is the identity function and $E[X \mid X]=X$

It does not help much with Question 2, mainly because $E[X\mid Y]$ is not a particularly enlightening concept when $X$ is completely determined by $Y$, and even less so when $Y=X$

Comment: Hmm interesting, thanks for your help. I know I'm wrong, but I have this feeling that the book I'm reading is being sloppy about using $E[X|Y]$ vs $E[X|Y=y]$ but I will go back and think through it more carefully.

Comment: For question 2, does this maybe work? If $X$ is the outcome of a dice roll, then the expected value of a dice roll given that you know the outcome of the dice roll can take on one of 6 different values with equal probability, which is equivalent to the oucome of a dice roll.